# In a linear model, if regressor is positively correlated with error, will OLS estimated coefficient be upward biased? why or why not?

Tags: least-squares, linear-model, bias

Suppose the dependent variable $Y_i$ is generated by $Y_i=\alpha_0+X_i\beta_0+e_i$, where $e_i$ is the unobserved error and $cov(X_i,e_i)>0$.  Using data $\{Y_i,X_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$, I get the OLS estimate $(\widehat{\alpha},\widehat{\beta})$.

Then is $\widehat{\beta}$ upward biased ($E\widehat{\beta}-\beta_0>0$)? Why or why not?

It would be great if you can show it mathematically and provide some intuition.

Thanks!